# Upload 2 images in an HTML form

Tags: php, html

I am trying to upload 2 images as part of an HTML form. Right now my PHP script is relying on the name of the elements being the same, so that I can reuse the code for both images, without having to change just one piece.

`upload.php`:

```
<?php
define("IMAGE_DIRECTORY", "images");

uploadFile("file");
uploadFile("file_1");

function uploadFile($name) {
    //If the directory for images does not exist, create it
    if(!is_dir(IMAGE_DIRECTORY)) {
        mkdir(IMAGE_DIRECTORY, 0777, true);
    }

    var_dump(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$name]["tmp_name"], IMAGE_DIRECTORY . "\\" .basename($_FILES[$name]["name"]))); 
}
?>
```

My HTML form:

```
<form id="create_card_form" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
    Front Text: <input type="text" name="front_text"><br><br>
    Front Media (Image or Video Link) <input type="text" name="front_media"><br><br>
    <input type='file' name='file' id='image_uploaded_front' accept='image'/><br><br>
    Back Text: <input type="text" name="back_text"><br><br>
    Back Media (Image or Video Link) <input type="text" name="back_media"><br><br>
    <input type='file' name='file' id='image_uploaded_back' accept='image'/><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="CREATE CARD" onClick="createCard(this.form)">
</form>
```

`Ajax`:

```
var form_data = new FormData();

var form_data_front = new FormData($('#create_card_form')[0]);
var form_data_back = new FormData($('#create_card_form')[1]);

form_data.append('file', form_data_front);
form_data.append('file_1', form_data_back);


$.ajax({ 
    url: "upload.php", 
    data : form_data, 
    type : "POST", 
    async: false, 
    cache: false, 
    contentType: false, 
    processData: false, 
    dateType : "html", 
});
```

However, when I use this form, the second image is taken in place of the first image, which I am assuming is because they are named the same. However, changing the names would result in the need to add a lot of duplicate code to process the images. Is there a way to do this with the same name?

UPDATE: I edited my Javascript and PHP script based on answers to my question. Now, it seems the problem is getting the images to the PHP script properly. Right now, with the code I have, there is an error in uploading the images in PHP.

Comment: _"However, changing the names would result in the need to add a lot of duplicate code to process the images."_ It shouldn't. Just put the processing code into a function and pass the element name as a parameter.

Comment: @AlexHowansky I tried that and updated my question, but can't seem to properly send both of the photos via Ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is no - you can't `POST` properties with the same name.

The solution to your problem is actually exactly what you're trying to achieve, just not in the way you're trying to achieve it. You don't want duplicated code (which is good) - so put code that needs to be ran more than once into a function.

```
<?php

uploadFile("file");
uploadFile("secondFile");


function uploadFile($name) {
    define("IMAGE_DIRECTORY", "images");

    //If the directory for images does not exist, create it

    if(!is_dir(IMAGE_DIRECTORY)) {
        mkdir(IMAGE_DIRECTORY, 0777, true);
    }

    var_dump(move_uploaded_file($_FILES[$name]["tmp_name"], IMAGE_DIRECTORY . "\\" .basename($_FILES[$name]["name"])));
}
?>
```

Edit: Just spotted [Alex Howansky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/453002/alex-howansky) beat me to the answer in a comment.

Comment: So this would require sending both the images to the script at the same time?